# react dnd nesting level on hover

Tags: react-dnd

I want to implement a drop system where if drop targets are nested you can cycle between them using the mouse scroll wheel (or have an automatic cycle happen after a certain amount of time) this will be particularly useful because many of the nested targets occupy the exact same areas on screen.

I'm presently thinking that I could use a callback passed down from the container that could be used by drop targets to register/de-register themselves when their hover function is called/when isOver prop changes but it's very coupled and I have to pass props into the DropTargets from the container, in the real world application there will be an unknown number of levels between container and drop target so I'd likely have to set up some kind of callback system, overall its not an ideal solution.  Also I'm not sure how to ensure the correct order when cycling as the drop targets don't know how deeply nested they are (see code below for how I've implemented this). Is there a cleaner way to implement such a system?

```
@DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)
export default class Container extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      bins: []
    };
    this.status = {};
    this._cycle = this.cycle.bind(this);
    this._register = this.register.bind(this);
    this._deregister = this.deregister.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    if (this.timer) {
      window.clearInterval(this.timer);
    }
  }

  register (name) {
    if (this.state.bins.findIndex(e => e === name) === -1) {
      this.setState({
        bins: this.state.bins.concat(name)
      });
      if (!this.timer) {
        this.cycledBins = [];
        this.timer = window.setInterval(this._cycle, 3000);
        this._cycle();
      }
    }
  }

  deregister (name) {
    if (this.state.bins.findIndex(e => e === name) !== -1) {
      const bins = this.state.bins.filter((e) => e === name);
      this.setState({
        bins
      });
      if (!bins.length) {
        window.clearInterval(this.timer);
        this.timer = undefined;
      }
    }
  }

  cycle () {
    this.status = {};
    const bins = this.state.bins;
    let activeBin = -1;
    for (let i = 0; i < bins.length; i += 1) {
      if (this.cycledBins.findIndex(bin => bin === bins[i]) === -1) {
        activeBin = bins[i];
        break;
      }
    }
    if (activeBin === -1) {
      activeBin = bins[0];
      this.cycledBins = [];
    }
    this.cycledBins.push(activeBin);
    this.activeBin = activeBin;
    this.status[activeBin] = {
      isActive: true,
      isOnlyActive: bins.length === 1
    }
    this.forceUpdate();
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        bins = {JSON.stringify(this.state.bins)}<br />
        cycledBins = {JSON.stringify(this.cycledBins)}
        <div style={{ overflow: 'hidden', clear: 'both' }}>
          <Dustbin name="Outer" register={this._register} deregister={this._deregister} status={this.status["Outer"]} >
            <Dustbin name="Middle" register={this._register} deregister={this._deregister} status={this.status["Middle"]} >
              <Dustbin name="Inner" register={this._register} deregister={this._deregister} status={this.status["Inner"]} />
            </Dustbin>
          </Dustbin>
        </div>
        <div style={{ overflow: 'hidden', clear: 'both' }}>
          <Box name='Glass' />
          <Box name='Banana' />
          <Box name='Paper' />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


const boxTarget = {
  hover(props) {
    props.register(props.name);
  }
};

@DNDDropTarget('Box', boxTarget, (connect, monitor) => ({
  connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget(),
  isOver: monitor.isOver()//,
  //canDrop: monitor.canDrop()
}))
export default class Dustbin extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    connectDropTarget: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    isOver: PropTypes.bool.isRequired//,
    //canDrop: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
  };

  componentWIllMount () {
    if (!this.props.isOver) {
      this.props.deregister(this.props.name);
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.isOver !== this.props.isOver && !nextProps.isOver) {
      this.props.deregister(this.props.name);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { canDrop, isOver, connectDropTarget, status } = this.props;

    const isOnlyActive = status && status.isOnlyActive;
    let isActive = status && status.isActive;

    if (!isOver && isActive) {
      isActive = false;
    }

    return connectDropTarget(
      <div>
        <DropTarget position={BEFORE} shown={isActive} />
        { isActive && !isOnlyActive ? '(' + this.props.name + ')' : undefined }
        { this.props.children ? this.props.children : (
          <div style={style}>
            { isActive ?
              'Release to drop' :
              'Drag a box here'
            }
          </div>
        ) }
        <DropTarget position={AFTER} shown={isActive} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```